# How to use the vector to store class object in overloading operator?

Tags: c++

This program will output the date in a file.
This is my  follow c++code:

```
#ifndef WINLOG_H
#define WINLOG_H
#include "Date.h" /*include date class;
#include "Vector.h" /*include my own Vector class;
#include "Time.h" /*include Time class;
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
 class winlog
{
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const winlog&C);          
  friend istream& operator >> (istream&input,winlog&C);  /*overloading 
   operator

    public:
    winlog(); /*
 winlog(Date Da);
  void setDates(Date Da); /*set method;
  Date getDates() const;  /*get method;
private:
    Vector<Date> D; /*create a vector class.
    Date Dates; 
};
#include "winlog.h"

 winlog::winlog()
{
//ctor
 }
  winlog::winlog(Date Da)
{
Dates=Da;
}

 void winlog::setDates(Date Da)
{
 Dates=Da;
}
 Date winlog::getDates()const  /*return dates
{
return Dates;
 }
  istream& operator >> (istream&input,winlog&C)
{
  Date Dates;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  input >> C.D.push_back(Dates);/*error here....
   return input;
 }

 ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const winlog&C) 
   {
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++) /**
    os <<C.D.at(i);
    return os;
  }   
    Date class here

  #include <string>
  #include "Vector.h"
  #include "Time.h"
  using namespace std;

  class Date{
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const Date&C);
   friend istream& operator >> (istream&input,Date&C);


public:
    void clear();
    Date(void);
    Date(int D,int M, int Y,char slash,Time Ti);

   void SetDate(int D, int M, int Y);
   void SetDay(int D);
   void SetMonth(int M);
   void SetYear(int Y);
   void SetSlash_dummy(char slash);
   void SetTime(Time Ti);

   void SetAll(int D,int M, int Y,char slash,Time Ti);


   int GetDay() const;
   int GetMonth() const;
   int GetYear() const;
   char GetSlach_dummy() const;
   string line;
   void PrintDate() const;
   Time GetTime() const;

  //overloading function--------------

    private:
    int dDay;
    int mMonth;
    int yYear;
    char slash_dummy;
    Time T;
  };
 #endif // DATE_H
```

Date.cpp   Date cpp file

```
    #include "Date.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include<iomanip>
    #include<string>

   using namespace std;

   void Date::clear()
  {

   dDay=0;
   mMonth=0;
   yYear =0;

   }
   Date::Date(void)
    {

    clear();
     }
   Date::Date(int D,int M, int Y,char slash,Time Ti)
    {
    dDay=D;
    mMonth=M;
    yYear=Y;
    slash_dummy=slash;
    T=Ti;

    }

   void Date::SetDay(int D)
  {
   dDay = D;

  }

  void Date::SetMonth(int M)
  {
   mMonth = M;

  }

 void Date::SetYear(int Y)
   {
    yYear = Y;

  }

  void Date::SetSlash_dummy(char slash)
{
 slash_dummy=slash;
}

   void Date::SetTime(Time Ti)
  {
     T=Ti;
   }

    int Date::GetDay() const
  {
      return dDay;

   }

int Date::GetMonth() const
{
    return mMonth;

}

 int Date::GetYear() const
{

    return yYear;
}
  char Date::GetSlach_dummy()const
{
   return slash_dummy;
}

   Time Date::GetTime() const
{
    return T;
}

   void Date::PrintDate() const
 {
     cout <<" " << GetDay() << "/"<< GetMonth() <<"/" << GetYear() <<         endl;

 }

   void Date::SetAll(int D,int M, int Y,char slash,Time Ti)
 {
    dDay=D;
    mMonth=M;
    yYear=Y;
     slash_dummy=slash;
    T=Ti;
 }



   ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const Date&C)
{

      os << " "<< C.dDay
              << C.slash_dummy << C.mMonth
              << C.slash_dummy << C.yYear << C.T <<"\n";

              return os;

  }
    istream& operator >> (istream&input,Date&C)
 {



       input >>C.dDay >>C.slash_dummy >> C.mMonth         >>    
 C.slash_dummy >> C.yYear;
      input >>C.T;



   return input;

 }
```

Time.h time class here

```
     #ifndef TIME_H
     #define TIME_H
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string>

  using namespace std;

    class Time
 {
     friend ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const Time&C);
     friend istream& operator >> (istream&input,Time&C);

  public:
    Time();
    Time(int hh,char sign,int mm);

     void setHours(int hh);
     void setMin(int mm);
     void setsignal(char sign);
     void setAll(int hh,char sign,int mm);

     int getHours()const;
     int getMin()const;
     char getsignal()const;



private:
  int hour;
  int min;
  char signalss;
};

   #endif // TIME_H
```

time.cpp    time class

```
#include "Time.h"

#include <iostream>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

 Time::Time()
{
 signalss=':';
}

 Time::Time(int hh,char sign,int mm)
{
   hour=hh;
   signalss=sign;
   if(min=0)
   min='00';
   else
   min=mm;
 }

  void Time::setHours(int hh)
 {
   hour==hh;
 }

  void Time::setsignal(char sign)
 {
   signalss=sign;

 }

 void Time::setMin(int mm)
   {
     min=mm;
   }

 void Time::setAll(int hh,char sign,int mm)
   {
   hour=hh;
   signalss=sign;
   min=mm;
    }

 int Time::getHours()const
  {
   return hour;
   }

char Time::getsignal()const
  {
  return signalss;
  }

int Time::getMin()const
 {
   return min;
 }

  ostream& operator << (ostream&os,const Time&C)
 {
  os <<" "<<C.hour <<C.signalss << C.min;

  return os;
}

  istream& operator >> (istream&input,Time&C)
{
   input >>C.hour >>C.signalss >>C.min;

    return input;
 }
```

Vector.h my Vector class

```
 #ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

  #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
 public:
   Vector();// constructor

  T& at(int i); //get the element at "i";

 void push_back(const T&elem); //add and element
 int getCount(); //get how many element are in the array
 int getCapacity(); //get the capacity of array
 bool isFull(); //checki if vector is full
 bool isEmpty(); // check if vector is empty
 void resize(int newSize); // resize the vector
 void create(int size); //create vector
 void clear();  //clear private variables
 int Size() const;

 private:
T* list;
T* start;
T* end;
int count;
int capacity;

 };


template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
  clear();
  create(2);

}

  template <class T>
 void Vector<T>::clear()
 {
list =NULL;
start=NULL;
end =NULL;
count =0;
capacity =0;
}

template< class T>
 void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& elem)
 {
if(count ==(capacity-1))
{
    resize(capacity*2);//can change to any value
}
*end =elem; //change the value at end position;
end++;
count++;
}

 template<class T>
int Vector<T>::getCapacity()
{
  return capacity;

}

 template <class T>
 int Vector<T>::getCount()
{

 return count;
}

 template <class T>
void Vector<T>::create(int size)
{
list = new T[size];
start=list;//point to start of list
end=list;  //point to start of list
capacity=size;

 }

 template <class T>
bool Vector<T>::isEmpty()
 {
  return (count==0);
 }


 template<class T>
 bool Vector<T>::isFull()
 {
 return (count==capacity);
 }


template <class T>
 void Vector<T>::resize(int newSize)
{

  T*newList =new T[newSize]; //create new array to the new size;
  T*newListPointer=newList; //pointer to the new list
  T*oldListPointer=list; //pointer to the old list

  while(oldListPointer!=(list + count)) //while there's still elements in 
   the 
  old list
 {
    *(newListPointer)=*(oldListPointer); //copy of value from old list to 
  new list
    newListPointer++;//move pointer
    oldListPointer++;//move pointer
}

start= newList; //start point to the new list
end= newListPointer;//end willl point to the ned of the new list
capacity=newSize; //capacity change to the new size of the array

delete[] list; //delete previous list
list=newList; //new list is new the list that will used.


}

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::at(int i)
{
    if(i>=0&&i<count)
   {
      return list[i];
  }
}

 template<class T>
 int Vector<T>::Size() const
 {
     return count;
 }



   #endif
```

How to store the unknown size of vectors by using the overload operator? i am trying to use the (int i=0;i

```
  01/02/1987 13:30
  11/06/1965 14:00
  21/10/1977 15:00
```

read the follow in date and time and ouput it.

Comment: I'm surprised you get any errors - most of your code is one long unterminated comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input >> C.D.push_back(Dates);` makes no sense. You might have meant

```
  Date Dates;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    input >> Dates;
    C.D.push_back(Dates);
  }
```

Comment: all right, how to use ostream operator to output the Dates? i try to use ".at(i)",but not working.

Comment: I have difficulty answering this question, mind-reading capabilities having yet to be perfected. Both `Vector` and `Date` are your own classes, for which you chose not to show any code.

Comment: ok, the C.D.AT(i) is work right now. but if the vector size is unknowns, what should I do? I am the beginner in C++, I only know how to store the specifies size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a `Date` first, then you can `push_back` it.

Assuming that you have an overload for `Date`,

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    Date d;
    input >> d;
    C.D.push_back(d);
}
```

If you have a file consisting only of `Date`s but you don't know how many they are, you can read until it fails (assuming that your extraction operator is well-behaved):

```
Date d;
while (input >> d)
{
    C.D.push_back(d);
}
```

or you can store the number of `Date`s before them, and read that first.

Comment: if the vector size is unknowns, what should I do? I am the beginner in C++, I only know how to store the specifies size of the vector???